# What do you call a disgusting mixture you don't want to drink?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

What do you call a drink (usually an alcoholic one, say a long drink or a cocktail) that you don't want to have, because you consider it a low quality, disgusting mixture, maybe even of suspicious, unclear origins?

Infamous drinks like *the sponge* (drops of shots spilled on the counter all night, then collected with a sponge, squeezed into a glass and sold to the undemanding, or some poor homeless guys) could be an example here. Or your friend's first, experimental cocktail... :-)

Context:
I want to reject a drink that I don't like, so I reply humorously and a bit sarcastically:

> No, thanks. I don't want any of this ____?

Comment: A weird  ***concoction***?

Comment: Not bad, Dan, thank you. Any more, maybe rather slang words for it? In my mother tongue it is called "a splash" in loan translation, which doesn't make much sense I guess, but maybe gives you an idea ... ;-)

Comment: Hi George. Welcome to ELU. I've edited your question for better formatting. Please avoid all-caps, and note that you need to have double-enters for paragraph breaks. Note also the quote formatting using `>`

Comment: @DanBron You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Backwash. Shit. Bud Light. You really give up that quick?

Comment: Backwash sounds OK, but implies that you get something organic with your drink, right? After drinking after someone else, for example ... Yuck! Bud light ... well ... for lukewarm beers without any bubbles perhaps? Or would you use it for any other booze you don't like too? Bud has nothing to do with beer here?

And the answer to your question: Nope. It's purely hypothetical. Though I prefer my own drink - one served for me excusively ... :)

Any other ideas for such a weird mixture?

Comment: I was about to offer _plonk_, which is what I’d probably call it—but when I looked it up, I found that nearly all dictionary definitions define that as referring specifically to cheap, bad **wine**, rather than just any kind of crap booze. @CuriousGeorge, is your native language by any chance Scandinavian? I’m not sure what the Swedish or Norwegian equivalents are, but in Danish, what you mention would be called _sprøjt_, which does indeed mean ‘squirt/splash/splurt’.

Comment: There's an easier solution: "I don't want to drink that. Whatever it is."

Comment: Piss/Shit/crap is probably appropriate for most purposes when dealing with being presented a beverage that is significantly sub-par. "No thanks, I'm not thirsty" if you need to be polite. Anyone offering a significantly disgusting mixture may as well have made a bowel movement/urinated in a beverage container anyway, as you'd likely have a similar aversion to imbibing said results.

Comment: I belive this is  "almost, but not quite, entirely unlike tea":)

Comment: A _"Snozzcumber Shake"_?

Comment: What's wrong with calling it "a disgusting mixture that I don't want to drink"? Sometimes I feel the craze to boil every little thing down to one word can make for a more difficult to understand sentence than just simply saying what you meant in a simple fashion.

Comment: Be innovative with.. disgusdrings

Answer (score 92):

***Swill***.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swill

> **swill** *noun.* food for animals (such as pigs) made from scraps of food and water
>
> food or drink that is very bad or unappealing

eg.

> What is this *swill*?! I'm not drinking that!

Comment: This is the word I had in mind when I first read the question. Couldn't for the life of me think of it, so thank you!

Answer (score 31):

I'd typically call such a drink a a weird ***concoction***. Per Merriam-Webster (via Google Definition):

***concoction***: *a mixture of various ingredients or elements.*
**synonyms**: *mixture, brew, preparation, potion *

Comment: Most people probably know the word from Jimmy Buffet's classic "Margaritaville", which contains the line "That frozen concoction that helps me hang on."

Comment: I don't think of *concoction* as having a negative tone by itself, though. Only in a context like *What is that dreadful concoction?*

Comment: I agree that it doesn't have the negative tone by itself, but it _readily_ gets it in this context.

Comment: For me, it just cries out to be called a ***vile** concoction*.

Comment: The word concoction makes me think of a mad scientist in a castle's basement *concocting* some sort of volatile alchemical potion.

Answer (score 18):

[Slop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slop): ( from TFD)

> - Unappetizing watery food or soup.
> - Often, slops. The dirty water or liquid refuse of a household.

[Slop Monster](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Slop%20Monster) : ( from The Urban dictionary)

> - When an otherwise sane, normal girl drinks too much alcohol and transforms into a stumbling, word slurring, wardrobe malfunctioning all around hot mess.
>
>   - Please don't let me drink tequila tonight, unless you want the Slop Monster to rear its ugly head.

Comment: +1 for slop, that's the first thing i thought of. it's a funny sounding word and gets the humor across without being particularly offensive. "i don't want any of that slop!" is definitely the kind of thing i would say if my friend made up a weird drink and was passing it around.

Answer (score 16):

No, thanks. I don't want any of this [Muck](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/muck)

> noun
>
> filth, dirt, or slime.

Although muck doesn't specifically denote a drink, I think that in this context where you're looking for a humorous/sarcastic response it will do just fine.

Answer (score 15):

There have already been some great answers (I like *swill*), but I thought I'd offer you another option anyway: ***bilge water***.

A bilge is the lowest part of a ship, below the water line. Water that washes up onto the ship's deck usually ends up down there, as well as other spills (detergents, oil, urine), etc. I'm sure you can imagine that it something you would not like to drink.

Bilge water needs to be pumped out from time to time, or on smaller or older vessels, may be removed using buckets.

Comment: This is a nice link which also explains that *bilge* is slang for nonsense, rubbish, rot.  http://www.lexicolatry.com/2013/06/bilge.html

Comment: Bilge also builds up in aircraft (mostly by way of condensation and spillage), and very nasty stuff it is there, too (very corrosive).

Answer (score 10):

Depending on what shortcoming you are complaining about, your choice may vary. Here are a few ideas.

If you want to suggest they may be trying to poison you:

**[Witches' brew](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/witches%27%20brew)** (dictionary.com)

> a harmful or threatening mixture; diabolical concoction

**[hellbroth](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hell-broth)** (dictionary.com)

> a magical broth prepared for an evil purpose, as in black magic.

If you want to bring attention to the quality of the ingredients:

**[(like) dishwater](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/like-dishwater)** (Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

> describes a drink or liquid that is unpleasant because it contains too much water and has very little flavor

**turpentine**, **paint thinner**, or **acetone**
There are many byproducts of alcohol distillation, called *[congeners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congener_(alcohol))* that enhance or undermine the flavor. A poorly distilled alcohol might have more of the most distasteful congeners than your best brands. Acetone is one of these congeners, and it may actually be added to denatured alcohol to make it undrinkable. *Paint thinner* and *turpentine* aren't actually congeners, but they say the same thing about the quality of the drink.

**[Ripple](http://sanfordandson.wikia.com/wiki/%22Ripple%22_wine)** (The Sanford & Son Wiki, for nostalgic reasons)

> Ripple was a fortified wine produced by E & J Gallo Winery Low end fortified wine that was popular in the United States, particularly in the 1970s. Possessing a relatively low 11% ABV, it was originally marketed to "casual" drinkers.  Due to its low price, it had a reputation as a drink for alcoholics and the destitute.

Comment: "No thanks, I don't want any of this hellbroth" That's hilarious.

Comment: these words are all funny, but i can't imagine someone saying any of them, really. that doesn't mean you shouldn't or can't, but they're just not common words/phrases. you might be met with a "huh?", especially if you're not a native speaker.

Comment: @sgroves Unexpected words like these can lighten the mood of the remark, which I think was one of the requirements in the original question. I think words like *swill* and *slop* are too simplistic to be funny. (I guess if you're really drunk when you say them or hear them, they sound funny, but then everything is either funny or an insult.) If the mixologist has to pause and say "Huh? WTF did you say?" then it cuts the edge off the insult for a moment.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, the first word that came to my mind is [*sludge*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sludge). It's not an exact fit, but it might be, depending on the drink in question...

Comment: sludge might be cool depending on the consistency of the drink.  Sludge represents something thick, maybe even chunky..

Answer (score 3):

A simple word would be just "thing"

You know it's a beverage (well, something you drink instead of eat), you know it's supposed to be edible. Calling it "thing" implies that you find it alien, weird and generally not your flavor.

Or, just refer to it as a glass of nope, courtesy of Nopeville

Answer (score 2):

"Swill" would be my choice for the best answer, but *dreck* was something that immediately came to my mind.

"I'm not drinking that dreck!"

For what it's worth "dreck" even sounds like "drink" so perhaps has a little more "literary flair". :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't want any of this *gloop*!

Comment: I'd say that *gloop* might imply an unwarranted viscosity.

Comment: @tobyink: Granted, but it adds a certain poetry that I think works well whether the liquid is _actually_ viscous or not. A bit like how saying "I'm not drinking that piss!" doesn't mean the drink is _actually_ urine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few drinks named for either an indiscriminate mixing of drinks or else a term for leftovers at the bar.

The term for an indiscriminate mixture varies by your locale, but it might be called either a graveyard or a suicide.  Though note that these usually refer to a mixture of every fountain drink at a restaurant.

For leftovers, you mention the sponge shot, but there's also the mat shot, where the bar mat that has been accumulating spilled drinks in the process of mixing all night is drained.  This is also regionally known as either an LA Freeway or a New Jersey Turnpike.  To me these have the sense of either the various drek accumulated on the road from all the drivers, or maybe the result of a multi-car pileup on the road.

Besides that, there's the term Fallen Soldier which is a term for leftover nearly drained drinks (usually with some quantity of backwash).

Answer (score 0):

You might refer to the drink as *grog*, although that may be a more meaningful term when your audience has some military experience. The *grog bowl* is traditionally found at formal military dinner/social events, and the drink in the grog bowl is usually intended to provoke the disgusted reaction you describe by design.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_in#Violations_of_etiquette_and_other_traditions):

> At some mess nights, violators of the mess are obliged to publicly drink from a grog bowl in front of the mess attendees. The grog is sometimes contained in a toilet bowl, consisting of various alcoholic beverages mixed together. As a more disgusting effect, the grog may also contain floating solids, such as meatballs, raw oysters, or Tootsie Rolls. The tradition of drinking grog originated with the British Navy. Grog consisted of the regulation rum ration diluted with water to discourage binge drinking. In modern times, grog comes in two varieties: alcoholic and non-alcoholic, the latter of which may contain anything that will make it less appealing to the taste, including hot sauce. For additional effect, the drinker may be required to drink from a boot.

[Another informative article](http://www.102iw.ang.af.mil/news/story.asp?id=123360687) explains the grog bowl by saying:

> What is the grog bowl? The main interest at a dining-in is the grog bowl. Plenty of different liquid ingredients are added to the grog bowl, and ultimately, a less than appetizing drink is made. It may look unsavory, but it is not undrinkable.

Dictionaries don't seem to make mention of that meaning, though, so my suggested answer here is admittedly of limited use. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/grog) makes *grog* sound a little tasty (“an alcoholic drink made with rum, water, sugar, and lemon juice, often served hot”); [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grog) describes it as “diluted,” though not necessarily unsavory or disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Jungle juice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle_juice) is the name given to an improvised mix of liquor that is usually served for group consumption. There are countless recipes and even websites devoted solely to jungle juice. The term has also been used for similar less-than-reputable alcoholic concoctions. –Wiki

No, thanks. I drink whiskey, neat. I don't want any of your jungle juice.