# What is one word for a “messy mixture of a lot of ingredients”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that describes:  a mixture of a lot of things **that ends up pretty messed up.**

What would that be?

Comment: [What do you call a disgusting mixture you don't want to drink?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194266/what-do-you-call-a-disgusting-mixture-you-dont-want-to-drink)

Comment: If you would like to see "great" suggestions, then you should also add more detail in your question. Can you say what the context is? Is it cooking, science, business, beverages, social sciences...etc? Then add a sentence where this word would be used. For more guidance and tips, please see the info on the tag SWR http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info P.S Two users from the community have voted to close your question for lack of research, when  five votes have been cast , your question will no longer receive new answers. These votes can be reversed!

Comment: *Potpourri* means a mixture, but the connotation is usually strongly positive.  There's another better French/Cajun word for a mixture, but it's not coming to me just now.

Comment: @sumelic I think that explaining what was wrong with the words I found is a very nice idea that didn't strike my mind. I'll keep it in mind from the next time. Thanks.

Comment: Now, you're going to have to explain to me why: 1. you didn't [edit your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/334454/edit) to clarify 2. why the term [**amalgam**](https://www.google.it/search?q=amalgam&oq=amalgam&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=amalgam+definition) fits. One of its definitions is: *an alloy of mercury with another metal, especially one used for dental fillings.* What is **that ends up pretty messed up** about an amalgam?? If anything it is perfectly blended!

Comment: I'm just lost for words, you chose an answer that had no references, no links, and didn't even fit the question title and body.

Comment: I downvoted your question for two reasons. 1. You didn't respond to various comments that recommended editing your question. 2. You chose the wrong answer. Now, you can accept another answer by clicking on a check tick on the left side of another answer. If you edit your question with proper context and example sentence, this question can be reopened by voting. It's entirely up to you. Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: @Mari-LouA 1. I didn't edit my question because most of the words mentioned here did quench my thirst for what I was looking for and I wasn't looking for answers anymore.

Comment: 2. _"An alloy for dental fillings."_ may certainly be one of the definitions, but it certainly certainly [satisfies](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amalgam) the _mixture_ part of the question as much as other answers here. Now, as for the **ends up pretty messy** part, I agree it doesn't fit well, but it still worked for me because it had an added effect of being _molten solid_ (& hence messy due to the nature of it's state) that worked well in my case.

Comment: I agree that was my bad due to insufficient info as I admitted in response to NVZ's answer and I will make sure to keep this in mind from the next time on.

Comment: Additionally, accepting one answer doesn't make other ones irrelevant. They were all helpful to me but I can't _accept_ all of them. Can I? Isn't the point of this community to assimilate and share knowledge (like we did) rather than thinking about which particular answer was accepted?

Comment: Anyway for whatever it's worth, I've _accepted_ the well documented and answer that satisfies the question in **all mentioned** respects. Let's put a smile on that face now. Shall we? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My candidate is [hodge-podge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hodgepodge#English).

> **hodgepodge** ‎(*countable and uncountable, plural* **hodgepodges**)
>
> A collection of miscellaneous things; a jumble.
>   
> *His latest sculpture is a **hodgepodge** of kitchen clutter and scrap glued together. In fact, all his recent pieces have been similar **hodgepodges**.*
>
> - **1653**, Izaak Walton, *The Compleat Angler*
>     
>   Man's life is but vain, for 'tis subject to pain, / And sorrow, and short as a bubble; / 'Tis a **hodge-podge** of business, and money, and care, / And care, and money, and trouble.
>
> (Wiktionary)

Comment: Also the variant 'hotchpotch', which I would be more likely to use, which may be personal preference or regional one. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hotchpotch

Answer (score 6):

**Concoction** — [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/concoction)

> A concoction is a curious mixture of things, like a bunch of liquids stirred in a cup, or the elaborate and unbelievable story you make up to explain not finishing your homework.
>
> Mix eight different liquids in a glass and you've got a concoction. Scientists create concoctions of chemicals in test tubes, and a bicycle made of junkyard scraps is a concoction too. The word’s Latin root means “cooked together,” referring to when you heat metals in order to purify them. A concoction is also a tall tale told to get out of trouble or entertain someone. If your story has ostriches, trampolines, lasers, and Abraham Lincoln, it’s probably a concoction.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you would consider *olio*, which any dictionary will tell you is a hodgepodge or collection of miscellany. The word is ultimately from the Latin *olla* (pot), a word which the Spanish adopted for *olla podrida*, a spicy stew of mixed meat and vegetables. The literal Spanish for the full name means rotten pot, but neither the full name for the dish nor its shortened English cognate have a necessarily pejorative connotation.

Comment: A couple of times I have put something in my fridge, forgotten about it. To make a long story short, sometimes "podrida" can be a very apt qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

**Cocktail** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cocktail)

> *noun* 1.1 A mixture of substances or factors, especially when dangerous or unpleasant
>
> *"he was killed by a cocktail of drink and drugs"*
> *"A cocktail of substances is now burning from several storage containers, but fire authorities say the blaze is well under control."*

Comment: I think that although **cocktail** fits in the mixture part very well, it's meaning (in my opinion) is _generally_ associated with a nice mixture (nice as in which isn't messy). Don't you think?

I was looking for a mixture which ends up being messy/bad/repulsive. I guess, that's my bad for lack of details in the question.

Comment: @sidharth228 There's two ways to look at "cocktail". In my quoted examples, "cocktail" is a messy mixture and it causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

*Conglomeration* is a good one.

> a number of different things, parts or items that are grouped
>   together; collection: a loose conglomeration of pieces.

Comment: Is this your own definition? If not, you need to include the name of your source (and also a link if it is online).

Answer (score -1):

A *[mélange](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/melange)* is a mixture of often incongruous elements.

Comment: Hello, Jonathan. Just a heads-up. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you cite a reference (dictionary link) or some examples to support your answer?